# Gravatar is changing to my Facebook picture on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-picture

On Stack Overflow, I logged in just now and noticed my gravatar was changed to my Facebook picture (using Firefox). I never changed it myself and thought it was strange, so I changed it back. After that, I launched Google Chrome and logged in again from there, and my facebook Picture was there again instead of the Gravatar. I have no idea why this is happening, but wanted to report it here.

Comment: I assume you mean on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @FDinoff: Yes, edited.

Comment: Did you login with facebook?  Also you appear to not have a gravatar - that's why we're using the facebook one...we didn't consider this case though, hang on.

Comment: @NickCraver: Yes, I clicked on `log in` and then clicked the Facebook icon. I can change back to my old gravatar from my user screen, what do you mean no gravatar?

Comment: I can repo this (on Stack Overflow) simply by logging out, and logging in (with Facebook), even though I have a Gravatar which I've been using for years.

Comment: @JesseGood can you reproduce this now?

Comment: @Matt can you retry now please?

Comment: @NickCraver: It appears to be fixed. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @JesseGood awesome, thanks for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We intended to do this for Facebook users *only when they first login* (as facebook.stackoverflow.com did) - that logic wasn't correct.  A build is rolling out now to ensure it only happens on user creation (not every time you login).  You can unset/change it once in your profile if you don't want it, and it'll stick once the profile (since it won't even try to set it again).

A build is rolling out now that will behave correctly - give it a few minutes.